# Placing a link in carousel caption causes carousel to disappear on slide 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Pretty new to html5 and Bootstrap 3 but trying to make my ecommerce site responsive.  Very mysterious stuff. The issue here is that simply adding a link to my carousel caption causes the second slide to disappear during cycle and then stall.  To see this click http://www.abundant-yarns.com, view the carousel working fine there and then click the blue link on the left navbar, "Page showing carousel with link".  You will go to a page that differs only in the second line of the carousel caption containing a link.  There, when Slide 1 transitions, Slide 2 fails to show.  Viewing the source code of the 2 pages side be side, I can't see any difference.  Plus I just noticed that having the links in the carousel captions seems somehow to cause the li items in the footer to change to the link color and to also initiate the link.
I also notice that after the link is initiated, the 2 divs that were underneath the carousel are sucked up under the top navbar as those divs are visably shorter on the second page and their text is not visable.  Please give some guidance.  My goal is to have active links showing over each of the carousel slides and, of course, having the carousel work properly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where to start??  Under your stylesheet...your carousel caption color:black isn't closed off with a semi-colon.  Same goes for #myCarousel .item {height: 400px}....this is more than likely where your problem occurs.  You also didn't include semi-colons on your carousel height for any of your @media queries.  You must make sure to close your css properties with semi-colons.  If they are not then the rest of your css will be out of whack as well.  This is a good place to start. There are also typos in your css, such as fopnt-aize: 24px;  Fine comb your stylesheet.  Fix these errors and then let me know if you're still having the same problem

Comment: I get it.  I offially change my name to Mr. McGoo.  I'll fix it and let you know.  McGoo

Comment: that would be "officially" 8^{